# How to avoid firing multiple redux actions with real time firestore listeners

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

### Introduction

**A Little Warning: I do use Redux Toolkit**

I have bunch of lists, one of which should be **active**. And depending on some context, **active** list should be different. **For example** I have 3 lists (A, B, C) and let's look at following patterns:

1. **List B** is active and I decided to create a new list. After creating **list D**, **list D** should be active:

   - List D - active
   - List C
   - List B
   - List A
2. **List B** is active and I decided to change the page. When I come back, **List B** should be active as it was before changing the page.

---

### The problem

As I initiate the **setListsAction** from the beginning, it always listens to the firestore and gets invoked every time I manipulate with the store (add, remove, update) and then pass all the data to the reducer. For this reason, I can't control which action was actually performed. For this case in my **setListsReducer** I check if there's already an active list, if so, I don't change it (covering my second pattern in the **examples** section). However, with such logic I can't set **newly created list** as active, because there'll be always an active list that's why in my **createListAction** I pas a newly created list to the payload and in **createListReducer** I set payload as the active list. However, the caveat of this approach is that both **setListsAction** and **createListAction** gets triggered, so redux state gets updated two times in a row, making my components rerender unnecessary. **The cycle looks like that**:

- in **createListAction** I add list to the firestore
- firestore was updated, so **setListsAction** gets triggered
- **createListAction** dispatches fulfilled action.

---

### My Code

#### Actions

**setListsAction**

```
export const subscribeListsAction = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchLoadingActions.pending());
    const collection = await db.collection('lists');
    const unsubscribe = collection
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const lists = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const list = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
          return list;
        });

        dispatch(
          fetchLoadingActions.fulfilled({
            lists,
          })
        );
      });
  };
};
```

**createListAction**

```
export const createListActionAsync = (list) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<PayloadAction<any>>) => {
    dispatch(listsLoadingActions.pending());
    const docList = await db.collection('lists').add(list);
    const fbList = { ...list, id: docList.id };
    dispatch(listsLoadingActions.fulfilled(fbList));
  };
};
```

#### Reducers

**setListsReducer**

```
builder.addCase(fetchLoadingActions.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.lists = payload.lists;
      const activeList = state.activeList
        ? payload.lists.find((l) => l.id === state.activeList.id)
        : payload.lists[0];

      state.activeList = activeList;
    });
```

**createListReducer**

```
builder.addCase(listsLoadingActions.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.activeList = payload;
    });
```

---

### Sum

So I would like you to propose a better way to handle my problem. I tried to solve it, using change type on `docChanges` but when I init **setListsAction**, all docs' changes are type of **added** and workarounds may damage further implementations of the app. Probably, I need to give up real time database and use `get` method instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you eliminate the `createListReducer` and `listLoadingActions`, you should be able to do everything from inside the `ListsAction` hook. Using `await db.collection('lists').add(list)` should refire the listener on the `lists` collection once it's been added to the database successfully.

```js
export const subscribeListsAction = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchLoadingActions.pending());
    const collection = db.collection('lists'); // no need to await?
    let firstLoad = true; // used to determine whether to use docs or docsChanges
    const unsubscribe = collection
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        if (firstLoad) {
          const lists = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
          firstLoad = false;
          // Get and set initial active list?
          dispatch(
            fetchLoadingActions.fulfilled({
              lists,
            })
          );
        } else {
          // optionally fire dispatch(fetchLoadingActions.pending()) again?
          const listsCopy = [...state.lists]; // copy the existing list to mutate it
          let activeList = state.activeList; // store the current activeList
          querySnapshot.docChanges().map((change) => {
            if (change.type === "added") {
              const thisList = { ...change.doc.data(), id: change.doc.id };
              listsCopy.splice(change.newIndex, 0, thisList);
              activeList = thisList;
            } else if (change.type === "modified") {
              listsCopy.splice(change.oldIndex, 1);
              listsCopy.splice(change.newIndex, 0, { ...change.doc.data(), id: change.doc.id });
            } else if (change.type === "removed") {
              listsCopy.splice(change.oldIndex, 1);
              if (activeList.id === change.doc.id) {
                // the current active list was removed!
                activeList = undefined;
              }
            }
          });
          dispatch(
            fetchLoadingActions.fulfilled({
              lists: listsCopy,
              activeList: activeList || listsCopy[0] // use activeList or fallback to first list in listsCopy, could still be undefined if listsCopy is empty!
            })
          );
        }
      });
    return unsubscribe;
  };
};
```

Regarding the active list history, you could either use the URL `?list=some-id` to store the selected list with the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) or you could store an array called  `activeListHistory` in your state variable where you `push()` and `pop()` to it as necessary (make sure to handle cases where the old list no longer exists and where there are no entries in the array).

Comment: Thank for your efforts! Unfortunately such code won't work, because I subscribe on mounting and unsubscribe on unmounting, so If I change a page and then immediately go back, `firstLoad` will be true and If I move it out of the action scope all lists will have `added` change type. I think it can be solved if I track how many changes are made with `added` type but it doesn't sound very right.

Comment: @h1kiga that's fine and is supported by this code. All `firstLoad==true` does is instead of using `snapshot.docChanges()` and checking `change.type` on each and every document (as it will always be `"added"`) and having to splice in each document to the original array, it shortcuts to using `snapshot.docs` and `map()` instead for a performance boost.

Comment: After a while I did everything as it's intended. Thank you very much! Regarding history you've suggested, I've added `previousList` to the state and merge it with the list from the store which has the same id and it works magically fine.